# insert text for textbox tkinter python

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-text

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time
class __MENU__(tk.Tk):
    def insert_(self):
        while True:
            self.text_box.insert('end','hi\n')
            time.sleep(1)
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('700x350')
        self.title('AUTO-TDS')
        frame=ttk.Frame(self)
        self.text_box=Text(frame,height=13,width=30,wrap='word')
        #self.text_box.insert('end','Auto Trao Đổi Sub v1\n')
        self.text_box.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)
        sb=ttk.Scrollbar(frame)
        sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
        self.text_box.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
        sb.config(command=self.text_box.yview)
        frame.pack(expand=True)
        self.bnt=ttk.Button(self,text='start',command=self.insert_).place(x=500,y=300)
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    __MENU__().mainloop()
```

when i press start my interface is unresponsive
, I want to use while loop to print continuously, how to do?

Comment: Use `.after()` instead of while loop and `time.sleep()`.

Answer (score 2):

Loops mess with `mainloop`. Use `.after()`. Your while loop will keep going on for ever because condition is always True.

```
def insert_(self):
      self.text_box.insert('end','hi\n')
      self.after(1000,self.insert_)
```

---

If you want to use while loop., use `threading` module.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time,threading
class __MENU__(tk.Tk):
    def insert_(self):
        while True:
            self.text_box.insert('end','hi\n')
            time.sleep(1)
    def insert_text(self):
        x=threading.Thread(target=self.insert_)
        x.daemon = True
        x.start()
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        ....
        self.bnt=ttk.Button(self,text='start',command=self.insert_text).place(x=500,y=300)
       
if __name__=='__main__':
    __MENU__().mainloop()
```

Comment: I am required to use while . loop

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: def insert_(self):
        self.text_box.insert('end','hi\n')
        self.after(1000,self.insert_)
    def start(self):
        while True:
            self.insert_

Comment: @NguyễnPhúKhương, check my updated answer

Comment: @NguyễnPhúKhương: why are you required to use a while loop? That's almost always the wrong solution in a GUI program.

Comment: I use it to display information,
while loop is my main program